# phpVMS - Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'lastlogin' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to install a software called phpVMS but when I finish running the setup I get an error
`/var/www/fly/install/includes/Installer.class.php 278 Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'lastlogin' at row 1`
I have looked inside the file "Installer.class.php" and I cannot find the date value 000-00-00. How can I fix this?

Comment: [https://github.com/DavidJClark/phpvms_5.5.x/issues/19](https://github.com/DavidJClark/phpvms_5.5.x/issues/19)

Comment: That doesn't show how to fix it

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Spectarion, thanks, when I try to reinstall I get this error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ezDB_mysql in /var/www/fly/core/classes/ezdb/ezdb_mysql.class.php on line 0`

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://forum.phpvms.net/topic/3082-instalation-problem/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file `/install/sql/install.sql` change these lines:

```
`lastlogin` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',

`lastupdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

`postdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', - TABLE phpvms_pages.

`postdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', - TABLE phpvms_news.

`joindate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

`lastpirep` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

`submitdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

to

```
`lastlogin` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

`lastupdate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

`postdate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, - TABLE phpvms_pages.

`postdate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, - TABLE phpvms_news.

`joindate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

`lastpirep` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

`submitdate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

---

In file `/install/sql/structure.xml` change these two lines:

```
<field Field="lastlogin" Type="date" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0000-00-00" Extra="" Comment="" />

<field Field="lastupdate" Type="datetime" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0000-00-00 00:00:00" Extra="" Comment="" />

<field Field="postdate" Type="datetime" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0000-00-00 00:00:00" Extra="" Comment="" /> - TABLE phpvms_pages.

<field Field="postdate" Type="datetime" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0000-00-00 00:00:00" Extra="" Comment="" /> - TABLE phpvms_news.

<field Field="joindate" Type="datetime" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0000-00-00 00:00:00" Extra="" Comment="" />

<field Field="lastpirep" Type="datetime" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0000-00-00 00:00:00" Extra="" Comment="" />

<field Field="submitdate" Type="datetime" Null="NO" Key="" Default="0000-00-00 00:00:00" Extra="" Comment="" />
```

to

```
<field Field="lastlogin" Type="TIMESTAMP" Null="NO" Key="" Default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" Extra="" Comment="" />

<field Field="lastupdate" Type="TIMESTAMP" Null="NO" Key="" Default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" Extra="" Comment="" />

<field Field="postdate" Type="TIMESTAMP" Null="NO" Key="" Default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" Extra="" Comment="" /> - TABLE phpvms_pages.

<field Field="postdate" Type="TIMESTAMP" Null="NO" Key="" Default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" Extra="" Comment="" /> - TABLE phpvms_news.

<field Field="joindate" Type="TIMESTAMP" Null="NO" Key="" Default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" Extra="" Comment="" />

<field Field="lastpirep" Type="TIMESTAMP" Null="NO" Key="" Default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" Extra="" Comment="" />

<field Field="submitdate" Type="TIMESTAMP" Null="NO" Key="" Default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" Extra="" Comment="" />
```

---

Install again.

> The MySQL 5.7.4 change to make strict mode more strict by including
> ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_ZERO_DATE, and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE caused
> some problems. For example, in MySQL 5.6 with strict mode but not
> NO_ZERO_DATE enabled, TIMESTAMP columns can be defined with DEFAULT
> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. In MySQL 5.7.4 with the same mode settings,
> strict mode includes the effect of NO_ZERO_DATE and TIMESTAMP columns
> cannot be defined with DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. This causes
> replication of CREATE TABLE statements from 5.6 to 5.7.4 to fail if
> they contain such TIMESTAMP columns.
>
> **You can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns.**

Comment: This worked but now I have this error `/var/www/fly/install/includes/Installer.class.php 278 Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'lastpirep' at row 1`, I was looking through the install.sql and structure.xml and there are quite a few rows with the 0000-00-00 or 00:00:00 which I guess is outated

Comment: Thank you very much @Spectarion

Comment: No problem. Vote up and accept as correct answer so future readers could use it. :)

Comment: do you know much about phpVMS?

Comment: This is the first time I heard about it.

Comment: Oh right, you sound very experienced. Don't suppose you have any experience in creating multiple account creation systems as such so if a user creates an account on my myBB forums they also get an account on phpVMS

Comment: Sadly, no. I have never done anything like it. But hey, feel free to post anything you can't handle. I'm sure somebody will know the answer :).